# Android App not full size on 10.1 inch tab

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an app on android market which was working fine on tab before. I introduced an update did not change much of the design. But now all of a sudden the app is not coming full size on tab? I read few more threads here and everyone talk about min. version of sdk should be 8. But in my previous version of the app i was still using min. version of sdk as 4 but it was coming as full screen before on tab? Is there any other reason or way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10.1 tab has xlarge screen. Use `android:xlargeScreens="true"` in manifest. You have to use android sdk `2.3` or above for that as it support is available for 2.3 and above.

Answer (score 0):

try adding screen support in manifest file of your app

```
<supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />
```

Comment: will this would have made any difference? target=android-14 as this was 8 before and i changed it to 14?

Comment: please take a look at android documentation for more detail
    
    http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html